# Is there a site for virtualization or hypervisor questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been trying to find a site for virtualization questions. I'm about to test Proxmox VE, because I couldn't get passthrough to work on ESXi and the questions I have don't seem like Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) has a [proxmox](/questions/tagged/proxmox) tag with more than 350 questions. It also has a [vmware-esxi](/questions/tagged/vmware-esxi) tag with more than 3000 questions. One of the topics that Server Fault covers is

> deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms

I suggest you look at the Server Fault [help centre](https://serverfault.com/help) and other well received Proxmox questions on that site to see if your question would work there.